# Integrating Java with Scala: Extending from Scala classes

Tags: java, scala, abstract-class, extends

I have created a project that uses scala that has some abstract classes definitions such as:

```
abstract class A(n: String) {
    require(n!= null)
    val name = n

    var inputs: List[Input[_]]
    var outputs: List[Output[_]]
}

abstract class B(n: String) extends A(n){  
   def act
   def isValid : Boolean
   def getCs : List[C[_]]
}

abstract class C[Type]{
   var value: Type 
}
```

Now I want to use that project in Java. I have imported scala lib in a new project and added scala project in the build path. I am using eclipse.

However, when I try to do this:

```
public class CoolClass extends B {  
    public CoolClass(){ }   
}
```

**EDIT:**

I have some problems using this in Java that raised me some doubts. Let me enumerate them:

1. Can I use Lists from Scala or that gives errors in Java?
2. Why vars from A aren't recognized in classes that extend B in Java?
3. How can I declare `getCs` so it provides an interface with `List<C>` instead of `List<C<?>>` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm just assuming, that you implemented all the methods you define in you `class B` also in your java `class CoolClass`. What is missing here is the call to `B`'s constructor, as the error message says.

```
class CoolClass extends B {
  public CoolClass() {
    super("");
  }
  // methods implementations
}
```

There is no default constructor defined on your `class B`, so you have to explicitly call the one that is defined, which is `B(n: String)`.

edit:

1: You can use anything you want on both sides. Though the method names may be different in some special cases like anything that includes special chars in scala.

2: They are recognized, though they are not fields, but methods in the java code. You can access them with `this.inputs()` and `this.outputs()`

3: Try `def getCs[C]: List[C]`

Comment: The constructer solved some problems but I keep getting problems and many of them don't make sense. I keep with one doubt: Can I use Lists (from Scala) ? Or Java doesn't like that?

Comment: Class A has 2 vars that have a List as Type and Java can't recognize those vars as fields of the class A.

Comment: Is the code you posted the code you have problems with? Your `def getCs : List[C[_]]` will not compile, because `C` is not known. You are talking of 2 fields in the A class, could you please edit your original post accordingly?

Comment: Sorry for my incomplete question. I thought that most of the problems would be solved with the first problems I posted here. Added one more problem at my question to prevent repeated information on StackOverflow.

Comment: Edited my post to answer you new questions.

Comment: 1 - I was talking about Scala Lists

Comment: (Sorry forgot that enter adds the comment)

2 - I couldn't acess the fields of a class with `this.field().` Maybe I should declare a method for each field?

3 - Almost worked. However it returns a `<Object>` instead of `<C>`

I belive scala doesn't integrate that well with Java. Maybe I do the basic structure with Java and then I add some layers to my work with scala. Probly with classes that aren't going to be extended in Java and don't use Generic this works better.

Comment: Yes, so was I. I was just saying, that you can use any scala class in java and the other way around, this includes scala.collection.immutable.List.

Answer (score 1):

Your B class is essentially as you describe:

```
public abstract class B extends A {  
  public B(String n) {
    super(n);
  }

  public abstract void act()
  public abstract boolean isValid();
  public abstract List<C<?>> getCs();
}
```

Your CoolClass is missing the explicit super call in the constructor:

```
public CoolClass extends B {
  public CoolClass() { // override ctor with no string parameter
    super("defaultStringValue");
  }

  public CoolClass(String n) { // override ctor with no string parameter
    super(n);
  }
  …
```

As you can see Scala makes it so trivial to declare and call constructors we forget how much boilerplate they add in Java.